# odbc.ini file configuration for when using key value pair (not PWD)

Tags: odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Reading documentation [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-parameters.html).

I would like to use an odbc connection with Snowflake. I'm already able to get this working by adding `.odbc.ini` to my home directory with a configuration that looks similar to this:

```
[snowflake]
Description=SnowflakeDB
Driver=SnowflakeDSIIDriver
Locale=en-US
SERVER=ourco.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com
PORT=443
SSL=on
ACCOUNT=ourco.us-east-1
UID=MY_NAME
PWD=$MyPassword
```

This works. With this config, I'm able to create a connection and query our database.

However I would like to use odbc with keys instead of my password. Followed guide [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/key-pair-auth.html) on creating keys and added them within SF interface.

I then updated my odbc.ini file:

```
[snowflake]
Description=SnowflakeDB
Driver=SnowflakeDSIIDriver
Locale=en-US
SERVER=ourco.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com
PORT=443
SSL=on
UID=MY_NAME
ACCOUNT=ourco.us-east-1
PRIV_KEY_FILE=/home/rstudio-blah/keys/rsa_key.p8 # this is where I stored the key
SNOWSQL_PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE=potatoes{ # not my real pwd
```

When attempting to connect with this set up I got error message:

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [unixODBC][Snowflake][DSI] (20032) Required setting 'PWD' is not present in the connection settings.

I tried adding `PWD=` just trying to trick it with a null value but then got:

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [unixODBC][Snowflake][Snowflake] (31)
> Password not found.

I then tried adding `AUTHENTICATOR=SNOWFLAKE_JWT` which gave error:

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [unixODBC][Snowflake][Snowflake] (44)
> Error finalize setting: Marshaling private key failed.

How can I connect via odbc using a key value pair as opposed to a PWD?

Comment: Generate an encrypted version of the private key (remove -nocrypt on the openssl command) and add **PRIV_KEY_FILE_PWD** to the odbc.ini file.

Comment: Hi @Sergiu thanks for the suggestion, I did that when creating the key already though - the key does have a password which I have tried to use :/

Comment: To clarify, I tried using `PRIV_KEY_FILE_PWD=$my_key_PWD` instead of `SNOWSQL_PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE=$my_key_PWD`, where I was just clutching at straws

Comment: You said you're using ODBC, why are you trying to set a SnowSQL environment variable? As a test can you try adding in odbc.ini **PRIV_KEY_FILE_PWD=<private key pass>** and see if this works?

Comment: Hi @Sergiu, tried that now, `PRIV_KEY_FILE=/home/rstudio-myname/keys/rsa_key.p8
PRIV_KEY_FILE_PWD=blah`, gives error 'Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [unixODBC][Snowflake][DSI] (20032) Required setting 'PWD' is not present in the connection settings. '

Comment: I tried adding `PWD=` (just blank) but got a PWD is missing error. It seems I need to tell Snowflake I want to use key pairs instead of pwd but when I tried adding `AUTHENTICATOR=SNOWFLAKE_JWT` I got 'Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [unixODBC][Snowflake][Snowflake] (44)
      Error finalize setting: Marshaling private key failed.'

Comment: I will test it from my side and see if there is an issue with ODBC driver. I'll update you by tomorrow.

Comment: I configured today key/pair authentication on a test account and I used ODBC 2.22.1 for Linux and with **isql** I can connect without any issues. I added in **odbc.ini** the following 3 properties: AUTHENTICATOR=SNOWFLAKE_JWT, PRIV_KEY_FILE = <path>/rsa_key.p8, PRIV_KEY_FILE_PWD = <private_key_pass>. You're using RStudio and **nanodbc.cpp** I assume it's this [one](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/blob/master/src/nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp) so maybe that's an issue with RStudio only. Are you able to test with other apps, like **isql**?

Comment: @Sergiu apparently the issue was when setting the key in SF UI. With support help we tried unsetting and setting a new key but on a single line. Apparently the error above, 'Error finalize setting: Marshaling private key failed' is associated with syntax of the .pem key. When openning the .pem key that's generated in the shell, it showed for me across 4 lines. We just pulled them up into one long line and after that everything worked! I'm not 100% sure this is the issue, maybe just readding a new key solved it, but it's working now. Thanks for your tips thus far!